# C++ Destruction with Concurrency

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was reading through [Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2325.html) and below is the implementation regarding destruction order:

> • Define a static-duration object that lists pending destructions for
> groups of declaration-ordered objects. Call this list the
> declaration-destructor list.
>
> • Define a static-duration object that lists pending destructions for
> execution-ordered objects not initialized in the context of a
> declaration-ordered initialization. Call this list the
> execution-destructor list.
>
> • Define a thread-duration object that lists pending destructions.
> Call this list the threaded-destructor list.
>
> • When starting initialization of a group of relatively-ordered
> objects, create an empty threaded-destructor list. The set of
> static-duration object initializations executed within the dynamic
> scope of the initializations of this group of objects is called an
> initialization region.
>
> • For each dynamic initialization within an initialization region,
> non-atomically insert the destruction at the head of the
> threaded-destructor list. This list will capture the function-local
> objects initialized as a consequence of the initialization of
> non-local objects. The code can be as simple as an insertion onto a
> singly-linked list with nodes statically allocated.
>
> • When finishing an initialization region, atomically move the
> threaded-destructor list to the declaration-destructor list as a
> group. The code can be as simple as an atomic insertion onto a
> singly-linked list with nodes statically allocated. The atomic
> insertion can be done with a compare-and-swap-with-release loop, which
> will terminate rapidly. A read-acquire on the head of the loop will be
> necessary before traversing the list.
>
> • For each dynamic initialization not within an initialization region,
> atomically insert the destruction at the head of the
> execution-destructor list. The code can be as simple as an atomic
> insertion onto a singly-linked list with nodes statically allocated.
> The insertion has the same basic algorithm as above.
>
> • Upon program exit, iterate over the execution-destructor list and
> call the corresponding destructors. After those complete, iterate over
> the declaration-destructor list and start the corresponding group
> destruction concurrently. Within each group, iterate sequentially over
> the destructor list.

What does Destruction with Concurrency means and how it should be implemented?

Comment: "Provide some examples" is not really a valid question here.  Can you please reformulate your question to be specific and concise, rather than a wall of text written elsewhere?

Comment: What does Destruction with Concurrency means? Sorry since I myself is not able to understand from the topic hence have requested explanation with some examples? Examples makes understanding a lot simpler

Answer (score 0):

The paper you've linked is about certain types of construction and destruction, including global statics and function-scoped statics, for example:

```
class MyClass {
    const std::string& func() {
        static std::string str = "";
        str.push_back('?');
        return str;
    }
};

static MyClass myGlobal;
```

As the paper discusses, at some point `str` needs to be destroyed, and if `func()` is called after that happens, it is a problem.

The paper is aimed at compiler writers, not application programmers.  You typically won't need to worry about these things when writing application or even most library code--especially if you eschew multithreaded use of global and function-level static variables.